# Javascript error or hiccup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have been working on a menu to show a business phone number I finally got everything to work as planned but now I am having a javascript lag, hiccup, or some type of delay / acting funny.

I have everything on jsfiddle so here is my work
[Jsfiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/HourGrim/b9w61L0o/)

If I could add picture I would to show what is being weird but I will try to explain it the best I can.

So when you click on the menu it sometimes show the

> `<h3> and <p>`

correctly and other times you click it and it does not show the

> `<h3> and <p>`

or I ran into when I click the X menu it will still show the

> `<h3> and <p>` (message)

Comment: __Identifiers in HTML must be unique__ You are using `id="bar-1"` multiple times

Comment: Ah alright, the only problem that I could think of there though is I have `bar1` `bar2` and `bar3` which all are a button? So if they don't click the right one it wouldn't show up then correct?

Comment: what is the end goal? To display a different phone number depending which bar they click? Or to just display the same phone number on a click of any part of the menu?

Comment: @ADyson The goal is to display the same phone number for any part of the menu being clicked. Would I just do away with the `id="bar-1"` and `id="phone-1"` or how do I go about making it so it would work with the whole menu?

Comment: @HourGrim try this then. Much simpler. https://jsfiddle.net/b9w61L0o/1/ It just shows/hides it on the click of the container, rather than worrying about each bar.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you so much if you wish to make a _Answer Your Question_ I will mark yours as the best. Either way thank you.

Comment: @HourGrim done, thankyou. I made a further small simplification of the code - link to the latest fiddle is in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than trying to trigger the change on every separate bar, you can just trigger it on the element which forms the container of the menu. This is much simpler, since you only want to show/hide one particular element when the menu is clicked. 
**HTML**

The click events on the bars are removed, and the bars are given unique IDs to make them valid HTML.

```
<div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this)">
  <div id="bar-1" class="bar1"></div>
  <div id="bar-2" class="bar2"></div>
  <div id="bar-3" class="bar3"></div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

myFunction now calls showphone, and showphone is greatly simplified to just show/hide a single element:

```
function myFunction(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("change");
  showphone();
}

function showphone() {
  div = document.getElementById("phone-1");
  if (div.style.display == 'none')
  {
     div.style.display = 'inline';
  }
  else
  {
    div.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

Events in JS bubble up the DOM. So in this example, if you click on a "bar", since it has no click event attached to it, the browser will work its way up the hierarchy of elements until it finds an element that does have a click event (in this case "container") and trigger that event. This feature means you can define a whole area that's clickable, even though it contains lots of other elements within it, and not have to define a click on each of the contained elements.

Here's a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/b9w61L0o/2/

Comment: @vol7ron thanks for spotting the typo, corrected now

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it simple like this:

```js
function myFunction(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("change");
  $("#phone-1").toggle()
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
}

.bar {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 4px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.change #bar-1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-8px, 4px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-8px, 4px);
}

.change #bar-2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.change #bar-3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -6px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -6px);
}

.icon-bar {
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 4px;
}

ul.tab {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Float the list items side by side */

ul.tab li {
  float: right;
}


/* Style the links inside the list items */

ul.tab li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}


/* Style the tab content */

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  float: right;
}

.topright {
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.topright:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this)">
  <div id="bar-1" class="bar"></div>
  <div id="bar-2" class="bar"></div>
  <div id="bar-3" class="bar"></div>
</div>

<p class="fa fa-phone icon-bar">Phone numbers</p>

<ul class="tab">
  <div id="phone-1" style="display:none; float: right" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>Area / Place</h3>
    <p>This number is?</p>
  </div>
</ul>
```

But then you need to include jQuery and do the click event on the whole element instead of every "line".